# Impedir usuário de digitar tipo de logradouro

Tags: javascript, html, formulário, javascript-eventos

Meu formulário possui um drop para TIPO DE LOGRADOURO (Alameda, Avenida, Caminho, estrada, etc. a lista não é grande e poderia ser inclusa manualmente dentro do if) , e um input para digitar o NOME DO LOGRADOURO. Eu preciso impedir que o usuário digite o TIPO DE LOGRADOURO no campo NOME DO LOGRADOURO, para evitar duplicidade de dados. Dessa forma, se o usuário digitar "Rua das flores" no campo NOME DO LOGRADOURO, o formulário deve imediatamente remover a string "Rua ", seja no onblur ou no envio do formulário. Que função javascript posso usar para executar esta tarefa?

```
//drop com tipos de logradouro
        <div class="form-group col-xs-2">
            <label>Tipo de logradouro<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
            <select id="tipoLogradouro" name="itemImovel.tp_logradouro" required class="form-control">
                <option value="" selected></option>
                @foreach (var item in ViewBag.TipoLogradouro)
                {
                    <option value="@item.propriedade_dominio1">@item.propriedade_dominio1</option>
                }
            </select>
        </div>
//input para nome do logradouro
        <div class="form-group col-xs-4">
            <label>Logradouro<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
            <input type="text" id="logradouro" name="itemImovel.ds_logradouro" onchange="bucarCartorio(0);" maxlength="255" value="@Imovel.ds_logradouro" class="form-control" required>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Existem várias estratégias para isso, abaixo uma que deve ajudar.

```js
//Pego todos os tipos que existem 
const tipos  = document.querySelectorAll("#tipoLogradouro option");
//Pego o input com a informação inserida
const iLogradouro = document.getElementById("logradouro");


//Criando uma função que faz a verificação
verificaLogradouros = function(){
    //armazeno o valor informado
    logradouro = iLogradouro.value;
    //Itero por cada tipo
    tipos.forEach((oTipo) =>{
    //armazeno o valor 
    tipoLogradouroAtual = oTipo.value;
    //crio uma ExpressãoRegular para verificar o que foi escrito de maneira 'Case Insensitive'
    re = new RegExp(tipoLogradouroAtual, "i");
    // verifico que no valor informado, aparece o texto
    if(re.test(logradouro)){
        //substituo o tipo por texto vazio
        iLogradouro.value = logradouro.replace(re, "");
    }
    });
};

//anexo ao evento blur 
iLogradouro.addEventListener('blur', verificaLogradouros);
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, após alguns ajustes. A função só não remove o espaço que o usuário digitou após o logradouro, problema que consegui resolver usando trim()

Comment: Que bom que funcionou... Lembre-se de marcar a resposta.